# Center ImageView inside another ImageView in Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview

Well I have to fit one ImageView inside another one. It is smaller and has to be exactly at the center. I have both images scaled for different screen resolutions but I can test only on one phone and I am wondering if I set the second image's height and width with dpi to fit my screen resolution will it be perfectly matched on all screens or is there any property in Android aside from setting the height and width that will automatically center one ImageView inside of other ImageView?

Edit: It's in RelativeLayout and the ImageViews are at the top left so I haven't added anything specific to the because they by default are there.

Edit2: Well changing the first ImageView to be RelativeLayout helps center the second image inside of it but then the RelativeLayout grows too big and enlarges the image that is background. Is there a way to make the RelativeLayout be as big as its background?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:layout_height="250dp"  >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/base"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:src="@drawable/home"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/center"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_width="150dp"   
       android:src="@drawable/home"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"   />
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well yes this works but I need the RelativeLayout be as big as the image that I am setting for background on all screens and setting width and height to wrap_content doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't help. Edit: It works, I was using the wrong image.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put an imageView inside another. Hope the following code will be helpful for you.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/image_on_center" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` and then use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` remember the order you add the `ImageViews` will decide what is on top :)